# An Hilbert space problem

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have a problem with this problem, could anyone help me? thankyou very much!

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be Hilbert spaces, and let $x\in H_1$, $x\ne 0$ and $y\in H_2$.
a) show there is a functional $f\in H_1$ such that $\|f\|=1$ and $f(x)=\|x\|$

b) build an operator $T\in L(H_1,H_2)$ such that $Tx=y$.

For a), I have considered $f(y)=\frac{1}{\|x\|}\langle y,x\rangle$
(I have update an image beacause I can´t write on LaTex here)

For b) I have no idea for it, could anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. For a guide to use MathJax (which is very similar to LaTeX) here, please read [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $f_1:H_1\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the functional you found in part (a). you can define an operator $T:H_1\rightarrow H_2$ by the formula: 
$$\forall z \in H_1:T(z)=||x||^{-1}f_1(z)y$$
Its easy to check this operator is linear and its bounded because if $||z|| =1$ then:
$$ ||T(z)||=||x||^{-1}||y||\cdot |f_1(z)|\leq \frac{||f_1||\cdot||y||}{||x||}$$

And clearly T(x)= y

Comment: could you explain it a little more? Thankyou very much!

Comment: I edited the question to include the solution...

Comment: Hi, thank you very much!, one more question, its good to write  https://ibb.co/2093wg0 to prove that it´s bounded?

Comment: yes thats fine, you understand that you are using cauchy schwarts inequality there right? :) (also if you can, please accept the answer)

Comment: done, yeah, I have use C-S. thank you very much Danny!